# How do I fix boot problems after installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 14.4 (64bit) alongside the pre-installed windows 8.1 (64bit) on my laptop Dell Inspiron 7548 around 1 month ago (UEFI partition). For this purpose I used liveUSB according to tutorial (http://startubuntu.ru/?p=104328).

Everything worked good and I was able to switch between OS.
Recently, I tried to boot my laptop and received next massage on the screen:

> GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9
>
> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
>   lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible 
>   device or file completions.
>
> grub>_

When i boot and press F12 i can choose OS, so Windows is operating good, but the same problem with GRUB appears when I try to load Ubuntu.

So, i boot my laptop using the LiveUSB and choose "Try Ubuntu".
According to procedure described in Boot-Repair I received next information http://paste.ubuntu.com/11392466/
I don't know why sda7 (swap) is detected, but sda8 (as was ext4 a few weeks ago) not detected (I can show print-screen)

How can I fix it? How can I load Linux ?
Will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have an abnormal shutdown, that can cause data corruption. If Windows you run chkdsk, but for an ext formated partition you run fsck.

From liveDVD/Flash so everything is unmounted,swap off if necessary, change example shown with partition sda8 to your partition(s)
e2fsck is used to check the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of file systems. -p trys fixes where response not required

```
sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda8
```

if errors: -y auto answers yes for fixes needing response, also see man e2fsck

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda8
```

Comment: i try first    [sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda8], but it was errors, then try [sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda8] and it make some changes and sda8 can be detected.

Comment: so, now I can boot Linux only as "Advanced boot",

Comment: so, now I can boot Linux only as "Advanced boot", visualisation of some letters are missed or strange. When I try boot last updates of Linux it was errors, so I must turning off the computer (an abnormal shutdown). So I try version 3.xx.30 Linux.

Comment: Never force shutdown your system. Use Alt+SysRq R-E-I-S-U-B instead. (For newer laptops they don't bother adding the SysRq print to the key, but it's the same as the PrtScr key)

Holding down Alt and SysRq (which is the Print Screen key) while slowly typing REISUB
R-E-I-S-U-B to force shutdown
A good way to remember it is.
Raising Skinny Elephants Is Utterly Boring ...or
Reboot System Even If Ultimately Broken ...LOL.